# How to pass client date value as filter to server if both are in different time zones in Java?

Tags: java, datetime

I know this is not valid question but posting here to get any ideas/suggestions.

I am facing an issue with date filter when client and server are in different time-zones. I am saving the datetime value in database as per server timezone(converting from client timezone value to server timezone value) and again showing in client as per client timezone.

Example:

Client from Singapore timezone sends request at **2021-03-05 01:30:00(AM)** and saving this request in DB as per server timezone(IST-Indian Standard time) by converting it to **2021-03-04 23:00:00**.

Since it appears as **2021-03-05 01:30:00(AM)** at client side, when user search with  date 2021-03-05 (not time), not able to get results from server.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Use UTC for all time values.

Comment: @Henry: Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/ - using UTC for everything without carefully considering the consequences is not a good idea. It's usually okay for past instants in time, but it's not good for future values, and not good for recurrent events either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your wish correctly, this method gives you what you want:

```
public static boolean doesTimeFallOnDate(ZonedDateTime timeStoredOnServer,
        LocalDate filterDate, ZoneId filterZone) {
    return timeStoredOnServer.withZoneSameInstant(filterZone)
            .toLocalDate()
            .equals(filterDate);
}
```

It converts the stored time back to the client time zone. It then discards the time of day. So in your example we will again have 2021-03-05. Finally we compare this to the filter date.

Try it out:

```
    ZoneId clientZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore");
    ZoneId serverZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
    
    // Time in Asia/Singapore time zone
    LocalDateTime clientTime = LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.MARCH, 5, 1, 30);
    ZonedDateTime timeStoredOnServer = clientTime.atZone(clientZone)
            .withZoneSameInstant(serverZone);
    System.out.println("On server: " + timeStoredOnServer);
    
    // Date from client
    LocalDate filterDate = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.MARCH, 5);
    boolean dateIncludesTime
            = doesTimeFallOnDate(timeStoredOnServer, filterDate, clientZone);
    System.out.println("Included? " + dateIncludesTime);
```

Output is:

> ```
> On server: 2021-03-04T23:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
> Included? true
> ```

If instead you wanted to store the time in UTC on the server, just use `ZoneOffset.UTC` for server time zone.

Comment: Hi Ole, thanks for your solution. By seeing your answer, I searched same functionality at database(MySQL) side,fortunately found the convert_tz function and it worked with JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with Date formats use Unix Time:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

https://www.epochconverter.com/

Every date in computer memory is stored as an absolute integer value of seconds that passed since January 1st, 1970.

The easiest solution to your problem is to store Dates everywhere as integer value and only convert it to date format when displaying the data.

Comment: Storing everything as UTC without any information about the original time zone is advice that's often given as a cure-all for time zone issues, but it's fraught with danger. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/

Comment: (And most platforms store considerably finer precision than seconds now...)