# Java datetime offsets/timezones class?

Tags: java, datetime, utc

Ok this seems like its been done or handled somewhere in a class but not sure.
Problem is I have an event object with a start and end time. Then there is a main "day" object its compared against. Problem now is everything is UTC so it all works fine. So when user changes event object to use say eastern time with offset -5 on the event, its being compared against this day object with UTC time so of course you can get overlaps against the main "day" object because its two different timezones being compared against each other. This is of course bogus. Right now code is comparing date getTimeMillis to see if the end date time in millis is less than Day objects 23:59 UTC time or if the objects start time is greater than the Day object start time of 00:01.
So... is there a class out there that I can simply pass in the two date time's in millis, time zone and get a yes/no answer that handles all these offsets?
I of course could do it all manually using the "afterDate" or "beforeDate" stuff but was hoping there is some fancy built already to handle it all already?

Comment: All classes which treat a millisecond count as a date assume those are are milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC.  Your fix must happen before you convert your date-time and timezone to milliseconds.  Edit your question and show your event class, and show how you are comparing date-times, so we can suggest a better way to compare them.  You may also want to look at the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: Represent start and end as `Instant`. An `Instant` is a point in time and independent of time zone. Represent your day as a `LocalDate`. It’s a calendar date without time nor time zone. To check whether, say, a start time is on a particular day in, say, America/Toronto time zone, convert to `LocalDate` using `startInstant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Toronto")).toLocalDate()`. Then compare. The mentioned classes are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: Ok to clarify I am doing now

Comment: long holidayEnd = holidayDate + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);      if((holidayDate < event.getEndDate().getTimeInMillis()) && (holidayEnd > event.getStartDate().getTimeInMillis()))

Comment: was thinking of changing it too below. Adding the timezone to the holiday as well(which currently isnt using)
long holidayDate = holidayView.getDateInMillis();
 Calendar start = DateUtil.getCalendarByMillisInTimezone(event.getStartDate().getTimeInMillis() - timezoneOffset,timezone);

 Calendar end = DateUtil.getCalendarByMillisInTimezone(event.getEndDate().getTimeInMillis() - timezoneOffset,timezone);

Calendar hDateTime = DateUtil.getCalendarByMillisInTimezone(holidayView.getDateInMillis() - timezoneOffset,timezone);
start.after(hDateTime) && end.before(hDateTime);

Comment: Thanks for clarification and thoughts. Please paste into the question proper and format the code nicely so we have everything in one place and so that the code becomes readable.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `Calendar`. They are old and poorly designed. Similar question: [How to pass client date value as filter to server if both are in different time zones in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66494479/how-to-pass-client-date-value-as-filter-to-server-if-both-are-in-different-time)